# Proper way of disposing an IDisposable instance when using NUnit's TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, idisposable, testcasesource

I have two slightly different variations (TestsA and TestsB) of NUnit parameterized unit tests that use a TestCaseSource to pass arguments to the tests.  In each case I'm passing an instance of a class that implements the IDisposable interface (I am using the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class in the examples):

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("Tests A")]
public static class TestsA
{
    private static Control _CONTROL;

    [TearDown]
    public static void Teardown()
    {
        _CONTROL.Dispose();
    }

    private static class TestCases
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCase1()
        {
            _CONTROL = new Control { Tag = 1 };
            yield return new TestCaseData(_CONTROL);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCase2()
        {
            _CONTROL = new Control { Tag = 2 };
            yield return new TestCaseData(_CONTROL);
        }
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCases), nameof(TestCases.TestCase1))]
    public static void Test1(Control control)
    {
        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(control));
        Assert.AreEqual(1, (int)control.Tag);
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCases), nameof(TestCases.TestCase2))]
    public static void Test2(Control control)
    {
        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(control));
        Assert.AreEqual(2, (int)control.Tag);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
[Category("Tests B")]
public static class TestsB
{
    private static class TestCases
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCase1()
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(new Control { Tag = 1 });
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCase2()
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(new Control { Tag = 2 });
        }
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCases), nameof(TestCases.TestCase1))]
    public static void Test1(Control control)
    {
        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(control));
        Assert.AreEqual(1, (int)control.Tag);
        control.Dispose();
    }

    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCases), nameof(TestCases.TestCase2))]
    public static void Test2(Control control)
    {
        if (control == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(control));
        Assert.AreEqual(2, (int)control.Tag);
        control.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am trying to come up with the proper way of disposing of the IDisposable instances.  The tests in the TestsA class use a TearDown method to do the disposing.  In TestsB I am disposing the instance immediately after the Assert.  But regardless of how I do it I end up with a CA2000 warning.  The warning's description is slightly different for TestsA and TestsB:

**TestsA:**
Warning CA2000  In method 'TestsA.TestCases.TestCase1()', object 'new Control()' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new Control()' before all references to it are out of scope.

**TestsB:**
Warning CA2000  In method 'TestsB.TestCases.TestCase1()', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new Control()' before all references to it are out of scope.

My question is:  Is there a better alternative for disposing of an object passed to a NUnit test via a TestCaseSource, or can I just ignore the warnings?